# How to monitor only the static html for changes in a web page

Tags: android, jsoup, html-parsing

I have created an app to monitor web pages. The trick is, when there is a change in ads, my app detects for a change and sets off an alarm.

How to resolve this?

This is the code i use for fetching the html

```
                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

                    HttpGet get = new HttpGet( urlValue );

                    HttpResponse response;
                    try {
                        response = client.execute( get );
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        if (entity != null) {
                            InputStream is = entity.getContent();
                            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                                    new InputStreamReader( is ) );
                            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                            String result = null;
                            try {
                                while( ( result = reader.readLine() ) != null )
                                    sb.append(result).append("\n");
                            } catch ( IOException e ) {
                                Log.e( "readFromUrl", e.getMessage() );
                            } finally {
                                try {
                                    is.close();
                                } catch ( IOException e ) {
                                    Log.e( "readFromUrl", e.getMessage() );
                                }
                            }

                            line = sb.toString();
                            is.close();
                        }
                    } catch( Exception e ) {
                        Log.e( "readFromUrl", e.getMessage() );
                    }
```

Or, will this possible with jsoup ?

Comment: How do you currently compare old content with new content?

Comment: I have two lists containing the html values of URL. For every n minutes i check the html and compare second list with the first one.If the comparison is not equal, then the html has been updated.
Guess i am right !! @KrystianG